# how to call landscape and potriat layout depends on the mode change?

Tags: android

i added  in manifest file.I craeted two folders layout-land and layout-port,eg:main.xml in both folder, i stored xml file in corresponding folder.when i change to landscape mode it is calling layout-port containg xml.

Comment: no need to call orientation it will take android will take care about that..

Comment: android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" i removed here orientation in manifest till it is nt working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be make different xml file as like drawable folders (landscape, portrait) as below :

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

Comment: res/layout-land/main.xml, res/layout-port/main.xml i did like this is it correct,if so am not getting

Answer (score 2):

See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Defined them as different layouts and put them in the appropriate folders and the os will handle it for you

Comment: do i need to add any method to call xml file present in layout-land folder

Comment: No Android will automatically pick the correct layout folder for you depending on the device's current orientation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in landscape or portrait mode, Android looks for the layout file in either the -port or -land directory first, if it's not found then it falls back to the default layout directory.

Read more about resources [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

Answer (score 0):

FYI the Android Emulator (AVD) isn't able to recognize it's in landscape. Even if you press CTRL + F11 and it turns the AVD emulator sideways, it doesn't actually register with the appliction that it's in landscape mode. So in short, if you're running on the emulator, your application will always think it's running in portrait mode (and not look for any "layout-land" resource folders). Test it on and Android device and it should work perfectly :)